# Uunresolved dependencies with 2 projects with multiple sourcesets in IntelliJ with Gradle

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, kotlin, jvm

I am experimenting with using a common Kotlin source-set and 2 specific source-sets for JS and JVM in Gradle. I know there is a `kotlin-multiplatform` plugin, but I wanted to try if I can make a setup like this. It works by running `gradle` from the command-line, but IntelliJ complains that either in the JS or in the JVM project (never both the same time) it can nog find the common classes.

My directory structure is as follows:

```
- common
    - src/main/kotlin/MyLibrary.kt
- js
    - build.gradle.kts
    - src/main/kotlin/JsDemo.kt
- jvm
    - build.gradle.kts
    - src/main/kotlin/JvmDemo.kt
```

Here, the Jsdemo and JvmDemo are nothing more than:

```
fun main() {
    MyLibrary().sayHello()
}
```

The build-scripts are like this

**JS**

```
plugins {
    id("kotlin2js") version "1.3.41"
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
   implementation(kotlin("stdlib-js"))
}

sourceSets["main"].withConvention(KotlinSourceSet::class) {
    kotlin.srcDir("../common/src/main/kotlin")
}
```

**JVM**

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.41"
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        withConvention(KotlinSourceSet::class) {
            kotlin.srcDir("../common/src/main/kotlin")
        }
    }
}
```

When running the tasks from command-line, everything works. However, in IntelliJ, the MyLibrary() can not be resolved for 1 of the projects. Which projects it is depends on which one I open first. If I open JsDemo first it has issues with JvmDemo and vice-versa.

Any idea what causes this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA relies to a great extent on a fact that a single source file can only be analyzed once, as a part of a single module and in a single context (platform, dependencies, language settings etc.). If that assumption does not hold, it will still analyze the source file once, and won't do it for the other modules that include the file. This leads to the behavior that you are getting. Including a single source file in more than one IDE module is not supported.

Kotlin multiplatform projects solve this by actually analyzing the sources once but with proper context that tells the IDE about platforms and expect-actual matching. This is the recommended way to share code between platforms.